# Tempo limite para cada postagem

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Preciso de uma solução para apagar uma postagem ou um registro do banco de dados em 3 dias, no caso a postagem ficará disponivel 3 dias e depois será apagada. Penso em usar a seguinte linha:

```
DELETE FROM posts WHERE data_postagem (aqui que complica, penso em + 3 dias, porém como digitaria isso?) );
```

Comment: Utilize a função [`ADDDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate) para somar datas.

Comment: E como isso entraria nessa linha?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar duas funções para isso: `ADDDATE` ou `DATE_ADD` para adicionar datas ou `DATEDIFF` para calcular a diferença entre datas.

**Estrutura e Dados de Exemplos:**

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `postagem` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `titulo` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    `data_postagem` DATETIME DEFAULT "2018-10-23 00:00:00"
);

INSERT INTO `postagem` VALUES 
(null, 'Título 1', '2018-10-01 00:00:00'),
(null, 'Título 2', '2018-10-02 00:00:00'),
(null, 'Título 3', '2018-10-03 00:00:00'),
(null, 'Título 4', '2018-10-04 00:00:00'),
(null, 'Título 5', '2018-10-05 00:00:00'),
(null, 'Título 6', '2018-10-06 00:00:00'),
(null, 'Título 7', '2018-10-07 00:00:00'),
(null, 'Título 8', '2018-10-08 00:00:00'),
(null, 'Título 9', '2018-10-09 00:00:00'),
(null, 'Título 10', '2018-10-10 00:00:00'),
(null, 'Título 11', '2018-10-11 00:00:00'),
(null, 'Título 12', '2018-10-12 00:00:00'),
(null, 'Título 13', '2018-10-13 00:00:00'),
(null, 'Título 14', '2018-10-14 00:00:00'),
(null, 'Título 15', '2018-10-15 00:00:00'),
(null, 'Título 16', '2018-10-16 00:00:00'),
(null, 'Título 17', '2018-10-17 00:00:00'),
(null, 'Título 18', '2018-10-18 00:00:00'),
(null, 'Título 19', '2018-10-19 00:00:00'),
(null, 'Título 20', '2018-10-20 00:00:00'),
(null, 'Título 21', '2018-10-21 00:00:00'),
(null, 'Título 22', '2018-10-22 00:00:00'),
(null, 'Título 23', '2018-10-23 00:00:00'),
(null, 'Título 24', '2018-10-24 00:00:00'),
(null, 'Título 25', '2018-10-25 00:00:00'),
(null, 'Título 26', '2018-10-26 00:00:00'),
(null, 'Título 27', '2018-10-27 00:00:00'),
(null, 'Título 28', '2018-10-28 00:00:00'),
(null, 'Título 29', '2018-10-29 00:00:00'),
(null, 'Título 30', '2018-10-30 00:00:00'),
(null, 'Título 31', '2018-10-31 00:00:00');
```

**Exemplo com `ADDDATE`:**

Como já foi mencionado, a função `adddate` serve para somar datas. Dessa forma poderemos somar a data da postagem *+ 3 (dias)*. Caso a data seja menor ou igual a data atual, então significa que o prazo foi expirado. A expressão da função é: `ADDDATE('data', 'número de dias a serem somados');`, por exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM postagem WHERE ADDDATE(data_postagem, 3) <= CURDATE();
```

O código acima irá imprimir todos os dias que somado com 3, é igual ou inferior a data atual.

[**Demonstração**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89c41f/1)

---

**Exemplo com `DATEDIFF`:**

Aqui poderemos calcular quantos dias há de diferença entre a *data1* e a *data2*. É uma função mais simples e, no seu caso, acredito que será melhor utilizada. A expressão da função é: `DATEDIFF('data 1', 'data 2');`. O retorno será um valor inteiro positivo ou negativo.

```
SELECT * FROM postagem WHERE DATEDIFF(data_postagem, CURDATE()) <= -3;
```

O código acima também irá imprimir todos os dias que a diferença de dias seja igual ou maior que 3.

[**Demonstração**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89c41f/2)